# Scipy.optimize.minimize's x0 (initial guess) equivalent for pyOpt?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I need to make changes to a code to replace `minimize` function with `pyopt.optimization()` function.
From the documentation:

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)[source]
```

The parameter `x0` stands for `ndarray; Initial guess.`

I do have a list of initial guesses that I want to use but I can't seem to find where do I use it in `pyOpt`. I tried using it in the `value` parameter of `addVar()` method during defining problem statement. However, in the results, the value remains unchanged.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that the analogous capability to an initial guess, with upper and lower bounds, is provided in PyOpt through the addVar() interface.

See the Quick Reference at http://www.pyopt.org/quickguide/quickguide.html, note the section entitled design variables.

Also, it might be worthwhile to see if your problem is similar to one of the examples at  http://www.pyopt.org/examples/examples.html